# Force ruby selenium to work with untrusted certificates

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, capybara, selenium-firefoxdriver

For context I'm running ruby-rspec with selenium and capybara. When I navigate to the app_host I'm getting an InsecureCertificateError in the browser. How do I load a profile into selenium so that it will ignore the untrusted certificates? Below is what I'm currently trying to work with...

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer=false
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, profile: profile)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: :capabilities
```

see [selenium docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#ssl-certificates)

Comment: Eric this gives me a `uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Remote`

Comment: @Zack That's because it should be  either of Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)  or more likely `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)` -  The selenium docs are wrong, or haven't been updated to match the current class structure in selenium-webdriver